# Rename [plotly-python] to [python-plotly]

Tags: support, tags

The title pretty much says it all...

Most Python-specific library tags are of the form `[python-libname]`. For some reason this is not the case for `plotly` and it is reversed - [plotly-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plotly-python).

To keep things consistent, I believe it should be renamed to the common format. The tag currently has over 600 questions so I think an *official* renaming should be done rather than manual editing. `plotly-python` can then even be a synonym of the renamed tag.

---

Example of other language-specific `plotly` packege:

- [r-plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-plotly)

---

Examples of other Python libraries' tags:

- [python-regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-regex)
- [python-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-requests)
- [python-turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-turtle)
- [python-typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-typing)
- [python-collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-collections)

Comment: I assume that the [[tag:plotly-python]] was named for consistency with [[tag:plotly]] and [[tag:plotly-dash]]. Is that a relevant concern?

Comment: @CodyGray interesting point. But to be honest I'm not really a `plotly` expert, just a `python` frequenter. Still, from the guidance of [[tag:plotly]]: *"For the Plotly R package, please use tag [r-plotly]."* so changing as above would even be consistent with that (it's not `plotly-r`...)